# div is not found in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

I got to fix an issue after a product was upgraded to the latest version. The html was changed so the objects that are inside iframe and supposed to be hiden are visible now.

I did not do the customization to display the product inside iframe and I do not really understand how it works but I was told that I should look at this file `iframeloader.aspx` in particular function called `function hideTitle()`

I do not have access to the main application only to the iframe one. I can edit iframeloader.aspx. I update the original hideTitle function so it looks

```
  function hideTitle() {         

      var ele = $('#contentFrame');
      ele.load(function() {
console.log("test")
      var menubar = $('#header');
          if (menubar) {
console.log("test2")    
console.log(document.getElementById("header").style.display);
console.log(menubar.html())
              menubar.css("display", "none");
          }
      });
  }
```

in console I can see this

```
test - iframel...strator (line 700)
test2 - iframel...strator (line 704)
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

in firebug I can see the html `<div id="header">`

When the page loads I can see the object I want to hide appearing and then later on messages from console.log()

Any idea

- how I can hide the `#header` object and
- why the object is not found by jQuery and javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide it with this: `$('#header').hide()`

The stuff inside the iframe is hard to reach because it becomes a new window, modify it with this:

```
$('some selector', frames['nameOfMyIframe'].document).doStuff();
```

Comment: `$('#header', frames['#contentFrame'].document).hide();` gives me `TypeError: frames['#contentFrame'] is undefined` .  the html looks like `<iframe class="scaleFrame" id="contentFrame"`. Did I do it right?

Comment: give the iframe a name like - name="thisIframe", then use $('#header', frames['thisIframe'].document).hide();

Comment: I am not able to give it a name.

Comment: give it a name anyway with $('#contentFrame').attr('name','thisIframe');

Comment: Not sure it if helps but `$('#contentFrame').hide();` works

Comment: actually it doesn't work in chrome. Works in IE and firefox. Any idea what to do about that?

Comment: I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined` in chrome on `$('#header', frames['#contentFrame'].document).hide(); `

Comment: try $("#contentFrame").contents().find(whatever)

Comment: $("#contentFrame").contents().find("html").find('#header').hide(); works nice. Thank you again.